# Variable definition and memory allocation in C

Tags: c, memory, allocation, definition

As a beginner in C, i'm wondering what is the result concerning memory allocation for double definition of the same variable, that is:

First file: file.h

```
int data;
```

Second file: main.c

```
#include "file.h"
...
int data = 56;
...
```

Comment: That  wouldn't work, because you are declaring the variable twice.

Comment: Did that even compile? It is the same as using `int data;int data=56;` in `main` which is invalid as you can't have more than 1 variable with the same name in the same scope. Also `#include file.h` is wrong.

Comment: In the case shown, nothing interesting happens, the implicit initialization to 0 is overwritten later with an explicit initialization. As soon as another file of the program includes file.h, this may result in a multiple definitions error (depends on the compiler and linker, the C standard renders that undefined). TL;DR: Don't put such a definition into a header, use `extern int data;` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point 1. `#include file.h` is wrong. you need to write at least `#include "file.h"`

Point 2. The concept itself is also wrong, as both the variables are in global space. It will give you multiple definition error.

Note: However, if you do `int data = 56;` inside a function, it will be fine, as that point of time, it will become a *local variable* to that function.

Also, I would suggest reading something about [*include guard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). Otherwise, if you *define* variables in the header files, inclusion of the header file more than once in a source file will also generate multiple definition error.

The Best Practice:

- **Declare** the variable in the header file. [`extern int data;`]
- **Define** the variable in (one of the) source file(s). [`int data = 56;` / `int data;`]

Comment: Multiple tentative definitions are allowed; the header shown can be included multiple times (by the same file), but not by multiple source files, and include guards don't prevent that.

Comment: @mafso Right. That's why I mentioned the _best practice_ case.

Comment: I don't question the "best practice", but 1) "It will give you multiple definition error." -- only if included in several files and then it still depends on the compiler and linker, Gcc on Linux accepts it, for example. 2) "Otherwise, if you define variables in the header files, inclusion of the header file more than once in a source file will also generate multiple definition error." -- that's wrong and misleading.

Comment: @mafso, please correct me if i'm wrong, but I believe this has something to do with explicit initialization. if, in the header file, we write `int data = 5;` then all the cases will generate `redefinition of data` error. isn't it?

Comment: For portable C code: An implicit initialization (a "tentative definition") may be overwritten by an explicit one in the same translation unit. Multiple explicit initializations are undefined, as are multiple definitions not in the same TU.

Comment: Gcc supports tentative definitions (with no explicit one) as if they were a declaration only if another definition is given in another TU (and thus not throwing an error). I guess, this is mostly historic, my point is: There are popular platforms where this doesn't result in a compiler or linker error although the code is non-portable (and is undefined according to the standard).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *double declare* a variable, use

```
extern int data;
```

in `file.h`.

More stuff about [`extern` variables](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/).

Moreover, `#include file.h` is wrong, please write `"#include "file.h"`.